# preference between completely randomized or stratified/paired randomized design under covariate not predicting outcomes?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, experiment-design, statistical-power, causality, random-allocation

Consider potential outcome of $i-$th unit $Y_i=(Y_i(0),Y_i(1))$ with $0$ as control and $1$ as treatment and say $X_i$ is the only covariate associated to $i-$th unit. Assume $X_i$ does not predict $Y_i$. Suppose there are $N$ such units. The following is quoted from Rubin's Causal Inference pg 55 of sec 4.7.

"On the other hand, if the blocks or pairs are formed in a way unrelated to the potential outcomes (e.g., by randomly drawing units to assign block labels Bi), the eliminated assignment vectors are just as likely to be helpful as the retained ones, and in such cases, the precision of estimators for treatment effects in stratified or paired randomized experiments is usually no greater than that for the corresponding estimators under completely randomized experiments."

It seems the text is saying that as for precision of treatment effect in this setting($X_i$ does not tell anything on $Y_i$), I should prefer completely randomized design. However, in real study, I do not have true information on $X_i$ predicts $Y_i$. Say I do not have strong evidence on $X_i$ predicts $Y_i$ to design a study and it can only be done once due to cost.

1. Should I still proceed with completely randomized design adjust to covariates instead of stratified randomized experiment? If there is no association between $X_i, Y_i$ and precision of estimator of treatment effect under stratification is less or equal to that of completely randomized experiment(I would take this means variance of stratification is larger), then naively power of stratified design is reduced due to increase of variance.
2. Should I proceed with stratified randomized design only when I have strong evidence that $X_i$ predicts potential outcome vector $Y_i$?